# Two php7-apache docker images, one works, the other doesn't. Can't find the difference

Tags: php, mysql, docker, mysqli

I have two Docker images created on different days. One is able to connect with a separate mysql 8.0 image, the other is not.

The history of the images is that I made one that works, tweaked the Dockerfile for portability, then when that image didn't work, I rolled the Dockerfile back to the original - but it still didn't work. I added the `--no-cache` option to the build but that didn't help.

The details:

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    memcached \
    libevent-dev \
    libc-client-dev \
    curl \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    ldap-utils \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install memcached xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached xdebug

RUN service memcached restart
```

Here's the line in the php that works for one image and not the other:

```
mysqli_connect('mysql80', 'my_username', 'my_password', 'my_database');
```

The error is:

```
Message: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

However, when I run the following from the command line of EITHER running container, it works just fine:

```
mysql --host=mysql80 -umy_username -pmy_password
```

I run the containers with identical instructions except the port to listen on, and I connect them to the network with scripts that are identical except for the image name.

Other things I've checked in running instances of the two images:

1. `php -i` yields identical results except of course `HOSTNAME`
2. likewise, `phpinfo()` in the code produces the same results except ports and `HOSTNAME`.
3. `apache2ctl -M` is identical between the two
4. `apt list --installed` lists identical packages
5. I currently have them attached to the same bridge network, communicating with the same mysql instance.
6. They are running php code from the same mounted source directory (confirmed by altering the code).

For completeness, here's how I run the two images (Usually of course I would only run one at a time, but having both running does not change the behavior.)

```
# newer image that doesn't work
docker run -d -p 8787:80 --name awesomeApp \
  -v /path/to/php/src:/var/www/html \
  -e DB_HOST='mysql80' \
  awesomeImage:latest

docker network connect awesome-net awesomeApp

# old image that does work
docker run -d -p 8788:80 --name oldAwesome \
  -v /path/to/php/src:/var/www/html \
  -e DB_HOST='mysql80' \
  awesomeImage:oldOneThatWorks

docker network connect awesome-net oldAwesome
```

I've completely run out of things to try to find a meaningful difference between the images, and need to be able to modify the image and have it work. Any suggestions welcome.